# Table cell shrinks after finished Loading page

Tags: html, html-table

So I have to pages which are the same.  Each are displaying some articles in a table layout.  The table layout and CSS are the same.  However, the one page is listing hundreds of archive articles which after it gets about 80% loaded, the table cell that contains all the text shrinks to about 30% of the actual row width.

However, there is nothing different on the layout, properties, CSS.  The row containing the cell that is shrinking is the right width.  The odd thing is even if I put a "width="100%" on the cell in question, it still is short of the row's width by about 20%.

Any thoughts, suggestions?

NOTE: I removed the text and just left the actual layout and cell/table/row properties.
Correct page:

```
<tr>
  <td>
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="4">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td width="100%" valign="top" align="left">
       <a class="docnavigation" href="removed link ">
        <strong></strong>
        </a>
         <br>
          <span class="steelNewsArticleDate"> </span> - <span class="Normal">
         <br>
       </span>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Problem Page:

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="4">
   <tbody><tr>
    <td width="100%" valign="top" align="left">
       <a href="removed link" class="docnavigation"> 
        <strong>  </strong>
        </a>
        <br>
        <span class="steelNewsArticleDate"></span> - <span class="Normal">
       <br>
       </span>
     </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with a missing tag from a Wysiwyg editor cleaning up some bad HTML incorrectly.  So it was forcing what would have been a parent row into a child table row.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the width of the `<td>` that contains the table.  Setting the width to 100% only tells the table to expand to 100% of its container's width.

Comment: I think you left out what your referring to in your sentence.  The only thing not set to a width of 100% is the TD containing the table, which I mentioned (and I think you referred to) I already tried setting to width="100%".